# Select Column with multiple condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Get column value with condition from another column.
For example I have dataframe

```
Package   Drink  Age   Name
Full       Tea   50    Toni
Half       Tea   50    Stark
Full       Tea   20    Evan
Half       Tea   50    Christ
Quarter    Tea   61    Mark
Quarter    Tea   18    Rufallo
```

Then I want to get name only '''if package==full or Half and Age =>50'''

The output I expected is

```
Tony
Stark
Christ
```

I saw some guidance in internet, then I wrote `subdf= df[(df["Package"] == 'Full') | (data["Package"] == 'Half' & (data['Age'] >= 50)), 'Name']`

but it is not working. the error say, 'Invalid index error'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select only column `name` with mask, for check membership use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
subdf= df.loc[df["Package"].isin([ 'Full','Half']) & (df['Age'] >= 50), 'Name']
print (subdf)
0      Toni
1     Stark
3    Christ
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Your solution with multiple `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
subdf= df.loc[((df["Package"] == 'Full') | (df["Package"] == 'Half')) & 
               (df['Age'] >= 50), 'Name']
```